# Combinations of string that can be formed from characters

Tags: java, combinations

How can I form different combinations of string from set of character array in Java

For e.g.,

```
'h' , 'e' , 'l'
```

Results in,

```
h
e
l
he
eh
le
el
hl
lh
hel
leh
lhe
hle
ehl    
elh
```

Comment: i don't think that there are any library with such functional. what's about writing code by yourself?

Comment: So what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use trees. Read this article:

http://exceptional-code.blogspot.com/2012/09/generating-all-permutations.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
void permute( String input)
{
  int inputLength = input.length();
  boolean[ ] used = new boolean[ inputLength ];
  StringBuffer outputString = new StringBuffer();
  char[ ] in = input.toCharArray( );

  doPermute ( in, outputString, used, inputLength, 0 );

}

  void doPermute ( char[ ] in, StringBuffer outputString, 
                    boolean[ ] used, int inputlength, int level)
  {
     if( level == inputLength) {
     System.out.println ( outputString.toString()); 
     return;
     }

    for( int i = 0; i < inputLength; ++i )
    {       

       if( used[i] ) continue;

       outputString.append( in[i] );      
       used[i] = true;       
       doPermute( in,   outputString, used, length, level + 1 );       
       used[i] = false;       
         outputString.setLength(   outputString.length() - 1 );   
    }
 }
```

Comment: Will this deliver a result similar to what he's looking for, where he gets just an 'h' from char array ['h' 'e' 'l'] for a possible output?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to define this is to think about it as two separate operations.

First you are generating all subsets of the input string (which is call the `power set`)

Next, you are generating a list of permutations with specified length given one of those subsets.

Creating a function that performs the first operation, and then passing each outputed set as an input to the second operation will theoretically generate the result.

In code, think of it in the following way:

```
// Assuming command line params are the input to this operation.
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Set <Set <String>> powerSet = powerSet(new HashSet <String> (Arrays.asList(args)));
    for (Set <String> subset : powerSet) {
        // Permutations need order
        printPermutations(new ArrayList <String> (subset));
    }
}
/*
 * Power set can be generated recursively by considering the two cases: when an element exists in the set, and when the element doesn't exist in the set.
 */ 
public Set <Set <String>> powerSet (Set <String> set) {
   Set <Set <String>> powerSet = new HashSet <Set <String>> ((int)Math.pow(2, set.size()));
   if (set.size() == 0) {
      powerSet.add(new HashSet <String> ());
      return powerSet;
   }
   Set <String> inputCopy = new HashSet <String> (set);
   for (String element : set) {
      inputCopy.remove(element);
      Set <Set <String>> powerSetWithoutElement = powerSet ( inputCopy );
      for (Set <String> subPowerSet : powerSetWithoutElement ) {
          Set <String> powerSetWithElement = new HashSet <String> (subPowerSet);
          powerSetWithElement.add ( element );
          powerSet.add ( powerSetWithElement );
      }
      powerSet.addAll ( powerSetWithoutElement );
   }

   return powerSet;
}

public static void printPermutations(List <String> input) {
   printSubPermutation(input, 0, input.size());
}

public static void printSubPermutation(List <String> input, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
        // Swap from start to i
        String temp = input.get(startIndex);
        input.set(startIndex, input.get(i));
        input.set(i, temp);
        // This does: abc -> abc, abc -> bac, abc -> cba
        if (i == endIndex - 1) {
            output(input); // you've reached one permutation here
        } else {
            printSubPermutation(input, startIndex + 1, endIndex);
        }
        // swap back
        String temp = input.get(startIndex);
        input.set(startIndex, input.get(i));
        input.set(i, temp);
    }
}

public static void output(List <String> output) {
    for(String out : output) {
        System.out.print(out + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

As you can see, this approach although theoretically correct may not be the best approach as it uses a large amount of heap space and stack space to generate the powerset recursively. On the other hand, the generation of the permutations is not as difficult.